# if list is ordered return true else if list is not ordered sort the list

Tags: prolog

i want to write a program that get a list as input and is list is ordered return ture and if list is not ordered sort the list . i write a program that get a list as input and return true if this list is ordered and return false otherwise ( ordered(List) ) also i write a program that recieve a list and sort that and return the ordered list as output ( bubblesort(List,Ordered) ) but i can't merge them together to write a program that if list is ordered return true else sort the list . i think a lot but i can't. please help me
thanks a lot

Comment: Could you provide your code and an example of your expected output? Knowing what you're working with will help us help you.

Comment: BubbleSort is in general an algorithm containing an outer-loop and an inner-loop where you are swaping values within the inner-one, the outer one controlling how many times you need to iterate through (quadratic in worst-case; can stop after no swaps has been done during some inner-iteration). Remove the outer one and iterate only once counting the swaps needed. If there is none, it's already ordered. (Of course you can remove the actual swap and only count the need for one to keep the original list unmodified)

Comment: You can also give an up vote in addition to an accept vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for example i want ordered([1,2,3]) returns true as output and ordered([1,3,2]) returns [1,2,3] as output

That is not possible in Prolog. Prolog predicates are not like procedures in many other languages that can make destructive changes to data structures. In Prolog, like in many functional languages, "sorting a list" means computing a *new* list with the same elements in a (possibly!) different order.

So if you want a predicate that takes a list and can "return" a sorted version of the same list, you need a predicate with two arguments. The usual Prolog way here would just be to use the `sort/2` predicate. It works well even if the "input" list is already sorted (but note that it removes duplicate elements).

If you really want to encode the logic of "check for an ordered list; if it is ordered, return it unchanged, otherwise return a sorted version", you can do that like this, using your existing code:

```
list_sorted(List, SortedList) :-
    ordered(List),
    SortedList = List.
list_sorted(List, SortedList) :-
    \+ ordered(List),  % the list is not already ordered
    bubblesort(List, SortedList).
```

(I did not test your code.)

Comment: You could replace the first clause with simply, `list_sorted(List, List) :- ordered(List).`